# Finding Last Row - Referencing Excel Object Library in VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have written a short script that logs the time in a spreadsheet when I login to my computer but I cannot define the last row properly. If I was writing in `VBA` the below would execute fine but I receive an error when the `VBScript` is executed.

VBScript is taking `Rows` from `Rows.Count` as a variable so it throws an error because I have `Option Explicit` on. If i try and qualify it as `.Rows.Count` it thinks `xlup` is a variable.

Do I need to reference the Excel Object library in the `VBScript` or should I just be using a different syntax altogether to find the LR in `VBScript`?

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlapp
Dim oWB
Dim oWS
Dim LR

Set xlapp = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set oWB = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("H:\HR Stuff\time_management.xls")
Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

With oWS
    LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         .Cells(LR, 1).Value = Now
End With

oWB.Close True

xlapp.Quit
Set xlapp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**xlUp** is a constant known to VBA, but not to VBScript. You have to define it yourself:

```
Const xlUp = <Use Excel interactively to get the correct magic Number>*
```

- Meaning something like "Debug.Print xlUp"